# LDAP based user authentication for Kubernetes

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

There are some methods natively supported such as basic auth , X509 certificates and webhook tokens.

Is there some workaround/project to use LDAP for user authentication with Kubernetes. I need users to be grouped in LDAP , and then use role binding to bind the group to a specific namespace with a role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can integrate with LDAP, for example:

- Using [dex](https://github.com/dexidp/dex#connectors)
- With Torchbox's [kube-ldap-authn](https://github.com/torchbox/kube-ldap-authn) (hint: read this [post](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-LDAP-Authentication/))
- Vis [keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper)

Also, there's a nice intro-level [blog post](https://medium.com/@pmvk/step-by-step-guide-to-integrate-ldap-with-kubernetes-1f3fe1ec644e) to get you started.